# Age verification, ensure is not blank and not less than 18

Tags: javascript

it is supposed to make sure that the first 2 elem[0] and elem[1] are not blank and if they are to return and error or display the name
the second part is to give an error if the age, elem[2] is less than 18

```
function checkForm()
{


var elem = document.getElementById('myForm').elements;

if(elem[0].value or elem[1].value ==(""))
{   
    alert("Please enter your first and last name");
}
alert("Your name is " + elem[0].value + "" + elem[1].value);

if number(elem[2].value) < 18
{
    alert("You are to young to be playing on this computer.");
}
alert("Your age is "+ elem[2].value);


}
```

Comment: `.val OR .val == ""` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Please make the title describe the question, rather than your need to ask it. Also you should get into the habit of describing what is happening and how it differs from what you expected to happen: if you wrote wrong code, we cannot divine what you _meant_ to write from it (though sometimes, like now, it can be guessed).

Comment: Here's one tip: replace `or` with `||` and break your first `if statement` into two separate clauses, for example: `if (a == '' || b == '')` You can read about logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: You seem to be *guessing* at syntax. That isn't going to get you very far. You should sit down and read a tutorial on JavaScript rather than continuing to fumble around. Most of what you've tried above isn't even *syntactically* valid, never mind logically sound.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your first conditional

```
if(elem[0].value or elem[1].value ==(""))
```

This error in this line stems from a colloquialism in English: when you say "the cat or the dog is here", this is a shortcut for the proper English, which is "the cat is here, or the dog is here".

Programming languages usually don't have colloquialisms; your code evaluates `elem[0].value`, then performs a boolean "or" operation on it with the expression `elem[1].value == ("")` as the other comparator.

That is, your line is equivalent to:

```
if ((elem[0].value) or (elem[1].value == ""))
```

and I think it's clear that this was unintended.

You probably meant to write:

```
if (elem[0].value == "" || elem[1].value == "")
```

Note that I've also replaced the non-existent `or` with `||`, which means "or".

#### Your second conditional

In this line:

```
if number(elem[2].value) < 18
```

You forgot the surrounding `()`.

So:

```
if (number(elem[2].value) < 18)
```

Though it's not clear what you meant by `number`. Further study the text that instructed you to write that.

#### Other notes

Your indentation is generally messy.

I hope you are enjoying learning JavaScript. Keep reading your book and studying the syntax, because you generally have to get it precisely right: *details matter*!

Comment: Is `or` even valid in Javascript?

Comment: @StephenTG: Can't find any evidence of that on a _very_ quick scan of ECMA-262.

Comment: Well I mean, specs aside, it's also trivially simple to see that it raises a syntax error on the console in Chrome, so no, I'd say it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't believe I didn't see those stupid syntax errors that was there. I see I have A LOT of learning to do

Comment: @user3434812: Well that's the fun part

Answer (score 1):

looks like you aren't formatting your if() statements correctly.

instead of 'or', you should use `||` (two pipe symbols).

Also, correct format for the statement:

```
if(condition){
  what to do if 'condition' is true
}
```

so, correct format:

```
if(elem[0].value =="" || elem[1].value ==""){
     alert("Please enter your first and last name");
}
alert("Your name is " + elem[0].value + "" + elem[1].value);
```

use this formatting for your other code as well.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 if (!isNaN(number(elem[2].value)) // its a number?
 {
      if (number(elem[2].value) < 18) // add ()
      {
          alert("You are to young to be playing on this computer.");
      }
      alert("Your age is "+ elem[2].value);

  }
```